Pusher realtime Twilio WhatsApp with Angular and Laravel
I am using Twilio WhatsApp messaging to send and receive WhatsApp messages with my app and it working successfully but it's not a Realtime, I must reload the page to see any incoming messages. I installed the packages and configured it but it's not working
I ran php artisan install:broadcasting and configured the config/broadcasting.php
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'ably' => [
        'driver' => 'ably',
        'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
    ],

    'log' => [
        'driver' => 'log',
    ],

    'null' => [
        'driver' => 'null',
    ],

],

And configured the .env file
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=my app id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=my app key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=my app secret key
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap2

And I created the MessageSent Event
class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat');
    }
}

And in the MessageController I created the functions to receive the message from Twilio webhook and broadcast it to the event and to list and send the messages
public function receiveMessage(Request $request) {
    $from = $request->input('From');
    $body = $request->input('Body');

    $message = Message::create([
        'sender' => $from,
        'content' => $body,
        'direction' => 'incoming'
    ]);

    broadcast(new MessageSent($message));
}

public function index()
{
    return Message::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();
}

public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $message = Message::create([
        'sender' => 'employee',
        'content' => $request->content,
        'direction' => 'outgoing'
    ]);

    broadcast(new MessageSent($message))->toOthers();

    $twilio = new Client(config('services.twilio.sid'), config('services.twilio.token'));
    $twilio->messages->create(
        'whatsapp:' . $request->recipient, // Guest's number
        [
            'from' => 'whatsapp:' . config('services.twilio.whatsapp_from'),
            'body' => $request->content
        ]
    );
}

and this is the api.php routes
Route::post('/whatsapp/webhook', [MessageController::class, 'receiveMessage']);
Route::get('/messages', [MessageController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/messages/send', [MessageController::class, 'sendMessage']);

and in the Angular app I have the service file
getMessages(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/messages`);
}

sendMessage(message: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/messages/send`, message);
}

and the component where I have the chat container
messages: any[] = [];
newMessage: string = '';

ngOnInit(): void {
  Pusher.logToConsole = true;

  const pusher = new Pusher('1e341dd0ed82a6d559cf', {
    cluster: 'ap2'
  });

  const channel = pusher.subscribe('chat');
  channel.bind('MessageSent', data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.messages.push(data);
  });
}

When I open the Pusher debug events console and run the app for the first time I see three events

But when I receive a message no events fired in the debug console and I must reload the page to see the message coming from the DB, anyone can help me please?
Note: the time of the events in Pusher debug console is differ by 3 hours from my local time, can it be the cause of the problem?
